# Render partial with content input in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I am trying to DRY up some of my HTML in my application currently I have a block of HTML that will get re-used multiple times

```
            <div class="block">
            <div class="block_head">
                <div class="bheadl"></div>
                <div class="bheadr"></div>
                <h2>Configuration Needed</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="block_content">
                <div class="message warning">
                    <p>You have not create an admin user yet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bendl"></div>
            <div class="bendr"></div>
        </div>
```

What I would like to do is to create a partial or something along those lines and be able to pass in the content to the block header and content

Does anyone know of a way to do this in rails 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i do it is to have a views/shared folder. Then, i create partials inside and i call them like :

```
<%= render "shared/flash_error", :error => flash[:error] %>
```

where shared/flash_error is :

```
<% if error %>
    <%= error %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to have your partials in the partial folder, use this syntax :

```
<%= render :partial => "partials/your_partial", :locals => { :error => flash[:error] } %>
```